No overload matches this call. Typescript error when overloaded callback is passed from one overloaded function to another overloaded function
I'm new to Typescript and don't know how to fix the error

No overload matches this call

The simplest code that reproduces is here:
// This is my code
function outer<T>(fn: FnS<T>, value: T): T
function outer<T>(fn: FnD<T>, value: T): T
function outer<T>(fn: FnS<T> | FnD<T>, value: T): T {
    return inner(fn, value)
}

// This code is imported from a library, I can't change it
type FnD<T> = () => T;
type FnS<T> = (set: T) => () => void;

function inner<T>(fn: FnS<T>, value: T): T
function inner<T>(fn: FnD<T>, value: T): T
function inner<T>(fn: Function, value: T): T {
    return value
}

Link to the Typescript Playground
I think it's related to the fact that T should be inferred from callback types and somehow should be fixed using conditional types, but I can't figure it out.

Which code is imported from a library?  There's no reason why you'd want overloads for that example as written. Without ms/TS#14107 you'd need to write out the union signature manually, but if you do this you don't even need the two call signatures, so you could just write this version and move on. Conditional types won't make this problem any better. What, specifically, do you need that requires overloads?

The inner function with its overloads is imported, so I can't change it. If there were no inner overloads, it would be much simpler to declare outer.

Well, the inner function is written suboptimally. See ms/TS#14107 linked above. If your goal is to just move on, then use a type assertion as shown here; I could write an answer explaining further. If you have some other goal, what is it?

The compiler suggests you you that:

This type parameter might need an extends () => void constraint

Due to the fact that FnS returns void, and in your implementation this case is not foreseen.
Since you cannot modify FnD and FnS, my suggestion is to use those as the generics parameter T of the function, so that you can add the extends () => void bit. With this configuration, your current T should become ReturnType<T>.
The modified code should become:
// This is my code
function outer<T extends FnD<K>, K>(fn: T, value: K): ReturnType<T>
function outer<T extends FnS<K>, K>(fn: T, value: K): K
function outer<T extends () => void>(fn: T, value: ReturnType<T>): void {
  return inner(fn, value)
}

// This code is imported from a library, I can't change it
type FnD<T> = () => T;
type FnS<T> = (set: T) => () => void;

function inner<T>(fn: FnS<T>, value: T): T
function inner<T>(fn: FnD<T>, value: T): T
function inner<T>(fn: Function, value: T): T {
    return value
}

const fns: FnS<boolean> = (bool: boolean) => () => {}
const fnd: FnD<boolean> = () => true

const shouldBeBoolean = outer(fnd, true)
const shouldBeAlsoBoolean = outer(fns, true)

You can find it in this playgorund link where the errors have been removed and inference seems good.

Thank you, but shouldBeVoid should be T i.e. boolean. The idea is that inner always returns T no matter what overload of fn is passed to it.

I updated the answer. If you need something different please edit your question providing an example of how you are using the function and your desired returning type (e.g. my shouldBeBoolean)
